# Angular cssSyntaxError in application

Tags: css, angular

I have an error that comes from my `css` file.

The full error message is this:

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/all.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/assets/all.css)
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: myfolder\src\assets\all.css:5556:189: Can't resolve '../webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf' in 'myfolder\src\assets'
```

This is how my folder structure looks like:

```
My project
`-- src
    |-- app
    |   `-- components
    `-- assets
        `-- all.css
```

I tried putting my `css` code inside the assets folder didn't work. How can I fix this error, error occurs only with the `fonts` inside the `css` file.

Comment: The compiler is look for `../webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf` (relative path) from where you have this css file. So it's looking for it in `src/webfonts/`. Is that path right?

Comment: that's definitely not right than, I don't even have that folder

Comment: Do you have the `fa-brands-400.ttf` file?

Comment: I don't have it, I used it like this before ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">``` but instead I copied the whole code inside a local ```css``` file and now I use it locally

Comment: You css file is trying to locale the fontawesome font in a folder that doesn't exists. That's why the error. You can manually download that file and put it in the right directory or, if you just need to use fontawesome's icons, just install FA via npm.

Comment: okay thanks i will try it

Comment: You have an explained solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619062/unable-to-use-assets-in-url-in-scss-after-upgrading-to-angular-10/62619147#62619147